# How can I read in a list of objects from yaml using Spring's PropertiesConfigurationFactory?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

If I have a set of properties, I understand that Springboot's relaxed data binder will read in a list of properties (or yaml) and populate the matching object. Like so:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("devices.imports[0]","imp1");
props.put("devices.imports[1]","imp2");
props.put("devices.definitions[0].id","first");
props.put("devices.definitions[1].id", "second");

DeviceConfig conf = new DeviceConfig();
PropertiesConfigurationFactory<DeviceConfig> pcf = new PropertiesConfigurationFactory<>(conf);
pcf.setProperties(props);

conf = pcf.getObject();
assertThat(conf.getDefinitions()).hasSize(2); //Definitions is coming in as 0 instead of the expected 2
```

DeviceConfig looks like this:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="devices")
public class DeviceConfig {

    private List<String> imports = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<DeviceDetailsProperties> definitions = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<String> getImports() {
        return this.imports;
    }

    public List<DeviceDetailsProperties> getDefinitions() {
        return definitions;
    }

    public void setImports(List<String> imports) {
        this.imports = imports;
    }

    public void setDefinitions(List<DeviceDetailsProperties> definitions) {
        this.definitions = definitions;
    }
}
```

`DeviceDetailsProperties` just has an `id` field with getters/setters.

Strangely neither the definitions (objects) or imports (Strings) are getting populated.

Using SpringBoot 1.2.0.RELEASE

Answer (score 1):

When using the `PropertiesConfigurationFactory` in a manual way like this, it won't automatically use the `prefix` value in the annotation.

Add a `targetName` like so:

```
pcf.setTargetName("devices");
```

The corrected code would be:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("devices.imports[0]","imp1");
props.put("devices.imports[1]","imp2");
props.put("devices.definitions[0].id","first");
props.put("devices.definitions[1].id", "second");

DeviceConfig conf = new DeviceConfig();
PropertiesConfigurationFactory<DeviceConfig> pcf = new PropertiesConfigurationFactory<>(conf);
pcf.setProperties(props);
pcf.setTargetName("devices"); // <--- Add this line

conf = pcf.getObject();
assertThat(conf.getDefinitions()).hasSize(2);
```

Comment: As you found out yourself, this is not at the same layer. That factory does not know about `@ConfigurationProperties` at all. You can have a look to [ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/context/properties/ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java#L291) to understand how it's done.